# How do you activate a UISearchDisplayController when a button is clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uisearchbar

I have this `UISearchDisplayController` and so far it can only be activated (ready to type with a drop down `searchresulttableview`) when someone clicks the `UISearchBar`. Is there a way to make a button do this task? I will appreciate any answer I receive.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `UISearchBarViewController`. Do you mean `UISearchDisplayController`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Will edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `[searchDisplayController.searchbar becomeFirstResponder]` inside your button selector?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the docs for `UISearchDisplayController`. There is an `active` property and a `setActive:animated:` method.

Have your button action call this:

```
[theSearchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `UISearchBar` extends `UIResponder` just like a `UITextField`, you can simply call `becomeFirstResponder` on the search bar to give it focus.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickedSearchBar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)clickedSearchBar {
    [searchDisplayController.searchbar becomeFirstResponder];
}
```